# Moving repo from Bitbucket to GitHub after git-filter-repo

Tags: git

I am trying to move a repo from Bitbucket to GitHub, because I don't want to lose history or existing commits and tags. Unfortunately someone committed the aws provider files in the repo and I can't push to a new upstream because of these files.

So I have filtered out the path `_rep/.terraform` with

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path _pre/.terraform*
```

completely which included these files. Then I tried: https://rushabhshah065.medium.com/lets-move-repository-from-bitbucket-to-github-with-all-branches-and-commits-f93c7d3bda67

But although the big files are deleted in my local branch I get the same error if I try it without filtering:

```
remote: error: File _pre/.terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.37.0/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v3.37.0_x5.exe is 172.61 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File database/.terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.44.0/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v3.44.0_x5.exe is 181.50 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It seems you still have the files in your repo. You have not removed it properly using `git-filter-repo`. Please update the question by providing detailed commands used to remove the files.

Comment: edited the question with the command, it deletes completely the subfolder ".terraform" from the local branch but like i said, the error still the same